# Ajax Success Callback has different $.fn KVPs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a jQuery library [jcarousellite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/) .
The library adds the constructor jCarouselLite to the prototype of the constructor $/jQuery .

```
$.fn.jCarouselLite=function(){ /*"LOTS OF CODE HERE"*/ }
```

I have a jQuery ajax call (I use $.ajax),which is made on the document ready event `($(document).ready)` which invokes the success callback, the success callback has the following code :

```
 console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames($.fn));
```

I include inline/internal script before the body ends, which has the same code as above :

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames($.fn));
```

However, the output of the first `console.log` does not contain the constructor `jCarouselLite` while the output of the second `console.log` contains it.
I want to use it in the first Ajax callback, but since  it is not being found, I get a reference error.

Am I missing something?

NOTE: THIS IS NOT AN ISSUE WITH THE ORDER OF INCLUSION OF THE SCRIPTS: 
I HAVE INCLUDED SCRIPTS IN THE APPROPRIATE ORDER SO PLEASE DON'T SUGGEST THAT AS AN ANSWER.

Comment: This would happen if you included jQuery twice.

Comment: *"However, the output of the first"* which one are you calling the first one? the one in the callback? the one at the end? (hint, the one at the end should happen first)

Comment: I like your note at the end, since the fact is it's still going to be an issue related to how you are including the scripts. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including jQuery twice, and here is how I know that.

Lets say, you have the following code, with the commented log outputs:

**jquery.js**

**jquery.foo.js:**

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $.fn.foo = function () {
        console.log("Hello World!");
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

**mycode.js:**

```
console.log($.fn.foo); // function
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log($.fn.foo); // undefined
}, 1000);
```

The only way it would be possible for foo to become undefined one second later would be if you included jQuery twice, or you deleted the property from the prototype. Nothing in jQuery deletes properties from the prototype, so the conclusion must be you are including jQuery twice. The second copy of jQuery doesn't have the plugin initialized, therefore, 1 second later, when you log the prototype (which is on the new copy of jQuery), it no longer has the plugin.

To prove this, if you modified the code to the following, it should work, regardless of jQuery being included twice:

```
(function ($) {
    console.log($.fn.foo); // function
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log($.fn.foo); // function
    }, 1000);
}(jQuery));
```

The reason that fixes it is it takes the value of `jQuery` and stores it so that if `window.jQuery` is changed, your code won't be affected. If it continued to log undefined 1 second later you would know the prototype is being changed. (you should still avoid including jQuery twice, that's a waste of client-bandwidth/battery etc. and may affect load times)